# Cabeçalho e rodapé não funcionam no mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou dando uma olhada no mPHP pra aprender a fazer relatórios com PHP, devido a um caso que ocorreu no meu trabalho, agora quero me precaver e aprender a usar tal ferramenta, mas estou com problemas(tentei fazer semelhante ao do trabalho).

Não consigo colocar header e footer no formulário, já tentei de várias formas que vi na internet, mas nada funcionou.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Cada variável que eu colocar aqui está no mesmo arquivo, só vou separar pra facilitar a visualização.

Código:

CSS:

```
$css="
    @page {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }



    #cabecInicial{
        font-family: 'Century Gothic';
        color: #3864B2;
        background-image: url('imgs/cabecalho_relatorios_1_grande.png');
        background-position: right top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 70% 120%;
        background-color: #efefef;
        height: 160px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #corpoCabecInicial{
        height: 115px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    #dadosCabec {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 430px;
    }



    #corpoRelatCompleto{
        height: auto;//100%;//200px
        width: 100%;//1035    
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .esquerdaEspaco10 {
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .subtitulo{
        font-weight: bolder;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .apertoDeMao{
        width: 154px;
    }


    .apertoDeMaoMini{
        float: left;
        width: 78px;
        margin: 8px;
    }

    #infoCabecInicial {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        font-size: 12px;

    }

    #obsCabec{
        opacity: 0.7;
        background: #144385;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        width: 230px;
        height: auto;
        color: #fff;
        float: right;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        box-shadow: 3px -4px 3px 0px #336abd;
    }

    .textoFooter {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        float: right;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .footer {
        background: url('imgs/footerGambi.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: right;
        clear: both;
        //page-break-after:always;
        //position: fixed;
    }

    .basicHeader {
        background-image: url('imgs/cabecalho_relatorios_1.png');
        background-position: right top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 70% 180%;
        background-color: #efefef;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        clear: both
        font-size: 12px;
        float: left;
        position: fixed; top: 0px;//page-break-after:always;
    }

    .textoCabecGeral {
        float: left;
        font-size: 26px;
        color: #3864B2;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #corpoRelat {
        margin-top:65px;
        font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
        font-size: 12.0pt;
    }

    .indice {    
        font-size: 22pt;
        border-bottom: 1px double;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .numeroIndice {
        padding-right: 15px;
    }

    .subIndice {
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

    .tabelaSistema {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

    .tabelaSistema td{
        border: 1px solid #000000;    
    }

    .tabelaSistema th{
        border: 1px solid #000000;    
    }

    .tabelaSistema .tdLess {
        width: 15%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .tabelaSistema .first {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    #cabecTable {
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>"
```

;

footer:

```
$footer = '

            <div class="footer">
                <div class="textoFooter">
                    ********
                </div>
            </div>

    ';
```

header:

```
$header = '

        <div class="basicHeader">
            <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><img src="./2016.07.12 relato_de_------.pdf_files/maoGambi.png" class="apertoDeMaoMini"></td><td>
                    </td><td><!-- textoCabecGeral-->
                        <div class="textoCabecGeral subtitulo">
                            RELATO DIÁRIO
                            <br>-------
                        </div>
                    </td><td>
                </td></tr>
            </tbody></table>


            </div>
        </div>
```

header da 1ª página:

```
$firstCabec = '

    <div id="cabecInicial">

        <div id="corpoCabecInicial">

                    <div style="height: 23px;"></div>

                        <div id="dadosCabec">
                            <table>
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td rowspan="2">
                                        <img src="./2016.07.12 relato_de_----.pdf_files/maoGambi.png" class="apertoDeMao">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="subtitulo esquerdaEspaco10">
                                        RELATO DIÁRIO
                                        <br>Gerenciamento do ------------
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="infoCabecInicial" class="esquerdaEspaco10">
                                        #-------
                                        <br>08/08/2016
                                        <br>-------
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </div>


                        <div id="obsCabec">
                            Principais ........ ++++++++ -----------.
                        </div>






        </div>

    </div>


';
```

corpo:

```
$corpo = '

    <div id="corpoRelatCompleto">


        texto totalmente aleatório gerado pelo Lorem Ipsum

    </div>




';
```

Juntando o HTML:

```
$pdfCompleto = $css.$inicioCorpo.$firstCabec.$corpo.$fimCorpo;
```

MPDF:

```
require_once ('mpdf60/mpdf.php'); 

$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header, "E");
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer,"O");

$mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252'; 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfCompleto);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: where found ur library mpdf60? check https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf is best to convertion

Comment: on the official site: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: Boa tarde, não precisam escrever em ingles, estamos em um site do idioma Portugues ;)

Comment: é pq eu ia postar nos 2 e acabei trocando um com o outro na hora de postar.

Comment: Sim isto eu percebi, estou me referindo aos comentários, tanto seu quanto do KingRider ;)

Comment: mas voltando ao assunto do topico, vc sabe ja teve esse problema, sabe o q pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: @user3061516 nunca usei mPDF, mas ao que me parece o CSS do Header e do Footer não é o mesmo do corpo (posso estar enganado). Vou testar e fazer alguns testes.

Answer (score 0):

Estou com o mesmo problema. Estava usando o PHP 5.6 e MPDF, tudo funcionando perfeitamente. Atualizei meu servidor local para o PHP7 fiz todas as correções e por incrível que pareça a unica que não dei conta de resolver é a questão do Header e footer do MPDF que não são mais exibidos.

Segue meu código que funcionava até a atualização:

```
$html= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$dt = date("d/m/Y H:i");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c', 'A4'); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->SetAuthor($_SESSION['nome']);
$mpdf->SetWatermarkText('- ID '.$_SESSION['id']);
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
$mpdf->AddPage('P', // L - landscape, P - portrait
        '', 
        '', 
        '', 
        '',
        10, // margin_left
        10, // margin right
        15, // margin top
        45, // margin bottom
        5, // margin header
        15); //margin footer

 $footer = '<table border="0" width="800">
        <tr>
            <td width="400" align="center" valign="middle">QAP Questões - Conteúdo gerado de https:// - Impresso em: '.$dt.' - Pag. {PAGENO} de {nb}
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>';

$cabecalho ="<div width=\"1000\">
<div style=\"font-size: 12px; font-family: arial\" align=\"right\"><b><i>Continuação do conteúdo gerado de https:// - Impresso em: ".$dt."</i></b><br><br>
 </div>";
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($cabecalho);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
$mpdf->SetProtection(array('copy','print'), 'xxx', 'xxx');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($retorno['nome'].'.pdf', D);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com um problema similar, no meu caso o cabeçalho não era adicionado nas páginas subsequentes. Nos tutoriais que eu vi pela internet alguns montavam o layout através do PHP, no meu caso tinha feito um pouco diferente resolvi carregar o layout html inteiro com cabeçalho, segue abaixo meu código de exemplo:

Dentro do meu código PHP:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // Carrego o meu layout inteiro
$mpdf->Output();
```

Dentro do meu arquivo html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
           @page {
              header:myHeader1;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <header>
       <!-- Definimos um nome para o nosso cabecalho -->
       <htmlpageheader name="myHeader1">
         <div class="border">
              <div class="column-left">
                 <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/img/logo.png"/>
              </div>
        
              <div class="column-right">
                  <h3>Relatórios</h3>
              </div>
         </div>
       </htmlpageheader>
     </header>
```

Fiz um teste aqui para adicionar o rodapé nas páginas basta fazer o mesmo procedimento, primeiro nomear o nosso elemento html por exemplo:

```
<htmlpagofooter name="myFooter1">
```

Dentro do css:

```
@page {
 footer:myFooter1;
}
```